# Black screen and video/audio distortions with 4K60 output

Tags: ffmpeg, hdmi, tv, 4k-resolution, distortion

I have a computer which is connected to my AV receiver which, in turn, is connected to my TV. All devices and cables support 4K60, i.e., HDMI 2.0. All corresponding settings are enabled and Windows as well as Linux show me a 4K60 desktop (3840x2160 at 60 Hz) with Web browsing etc. working as desired.

However, whenever I open a video, be it in the browser or with a media player like VLC, the TV screen either goes completely black, or both, video and audio, drop out and/or become severely distorted for 1-2 seconds every 5-10 seconds. This happens on both, Linux and Windows. It makes videos unwatchable.

This issue disappears completely if I change the output to 4K30. It also disappears when I connect directly to the TV instead of going through my AV receiver. I assumed that any of the following components is at fault:

- One of the **HDMI cable**s - I replaced all of them and, in addition, tried all possible combinations on all connections just to be safe. However, since 4K60 works fine directly on the TV as well as when displaying a regular desktop or Web browser, the cables are unlikely to be the culprit.
- The **computer** or the **GPU driver** - I tried with another computer that is as different as possible, but the issue remains. Computer 1 is a 2016 Intel NUC with an Intel CPU/GPU, computer 2 is a 2022 Gigabyte NUC with an AMD CPU/GPU. I tried both, Linux and Windows with the latest drivers available. This seems to rule out the computer, OS and GPU driver.
- The **receiver** - I do not have another AV receiver to test, unfortunately, so the receiver may be at fault.

Since the receiver is, in my opinion, the only component that is likely faulty, I tried to narrow down the actual conditions under which the issue occurs so that I can avoid it or work around it. I can say for sure that the issue occurs with video-only playback, even when no audio is involved, but what makes me really scratch my head is this: **Only decoding video without displaying it** causes the issue to occur immediately. I mean, even without hardware acceleration, letting the CPU (!), not the GPU, decode a video makes the screen go black. Stopping video decoding restores the normal state of things. (FFmpeg command to reproduce: `ffmpeg -hwaccel none -i test.mp4 -f null NUL` with any 8-bit H.264, 10-bit H.264 or 10-bit H.265 video off the internet)

I though that maybe the CPU being under high load provokes the black-screen issue. However, running, e.g., OpenSSL in benchmarking mode yields 100% CPU load across all cores, but does *not* make the screen go black.

This begs the following **question: How can a certain type of CPU load** (un-accelerated video decoding) **impact the HDMI output such that my display goes black**, but only when the output is set to 4K60 (not 4K30), and only when there is a receiver between the computer and the display? From my understanding, since HDMI transmits raw data, it should not matter whether the displayed pixels come from a (CPU-)decoded video, a rendered Web page or anything else. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried videos which are not H.264/H.265 ?

Comment: @harrymc No, these two are the ones I mostly need and, as far as I understand, it should not make any difference which codecs are used. If you have a suggestion for another codec to try, I'll be happy to test it.

Comment: My favorite is the [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), Mega version.

Comment: Signals degrade with cable length. If it works with a single cable, but not when you double the cable leght by using two cables: You may need high end HDMI cables. Most cables aren't built to support 4k@60 signals beyond their own length.

Comment: @svin83 That's a valid point. However, would the AV receiver not amplify or regenerate the signal? Pass-through is turned off in the settings.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger That depends on your AV receiver. Does it have video-specific features/functionality, or just audio and input/output switches? Many non-video devices only have ability to copy audio from signals (for the amplifier) and pass them through. A good 4k@60 repeater will require high bandwidth throughput and will also make it alot more advanced & expensive to build than a simple interconnect.

Comment: @svin83 As far as I can tell, it does have video-specific functionality and was relatively expensive. The AV receiver is a Marantz NR1710.

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger As far as you can tell? Does it stream or play back video? Can you plug it into a TV and a network and stream video without needing other devices? Can you plug in a USB stick with video files and play them back? Anything else is just GUI overlay. That is not video capabilities. Using it to choose what video source you send to your TV is not video capabilities...

Comment: I checked the manual. It has upscaling but no real video capabilities beyond that. It may have repeater functionality. I don't really feel like reading your user manual so you won't have to.  It *does* support 4k@60 4:4:4 simultaneous input and output but it probably depends on settings and cables of sufficient quality(HDMI version Spec/etc). Try fiddling with pasthrough/upscaling/HDMI-CEC etc. Check your cables one at a time to make sure all are okay. See if *HDMI Drive* can be boosted in any of your devices.

Comment: @svin83 I already checked all the cables (see my original post above) - and even replaced them with brand-new ones that explicitly support 4K60. The AV receiver can produce overlays onto the HDMI output, so it must regenerate the signal. I did check the user manual and troubleshooting guides. The point is that there is no indication whatsoever why rendering a desktop or Web browser work fine, while rendering video does not - pixels are pixels. Further, how could a particular CPU load on the *computer* impact the way how the receiver processes or passes on the signal?

Comment: @svin83 Regarding your other question about streaming or playback: I go from HDMI in to HDMI out on the receiver, with no streaming involved. Regarding the playback of video files from a USB stick - which device do you mean I should use for that? The AV receiver cannot decode video files.

Comment: A simple overlay require far less sophisticated hardware than decoding and playback. That is why I asked for specific video features earlier. To understand how capable the device was. Yeah. pixels are pixels but cables and interconnects have bandwidth requirements. When you double the amount of pictures per second, the cables have to sustain twice the data rate. Why are you asking about a computer and CPU load? Full motion video will require higher cable bandwith than pictures that only change some pixels. Also if color bit depth changes, so do the bandwidth requirements.

Comment: @svin83: As described in my post above, 4K60 works perfectly unless in a few scenarios. The bit depth did not change at any point. Is is always 8 bits per channel, 24 bits total. I do not understand your comment how video would require more bandwidth at the same resolution and refresh rate. As far as I understand the HDMI standard, all pixels are transmitted without compression, so the bandwidth requirements are exactly the same for a 4K60 desktop as the are for a 4K60 video being played back (given, of course, that bit depth etc. are the same).

Comment: @AndreasUnterweger: Have you tried installing a codec pack (such as K-Lite) ?

Comment: @harrymc K-Lite uses libav[format|codec], as does FFmpeg, so there is no difference. Do you have any other codec that I should try apart from H.264 and H.265? I am happy to try VP9, MPEG-2 or the like if you think that they behave differently from H.264/H.265.

Comment: Not all codecs are the same. If one doesn't work, try installing another. I found the codecs in K-Lite to be very good, but no guarantee that they will help.

Comment: The [specs](https://www.marantz.com/en-us/product/av-receivers/nr1710) of your AV receiver say "HDMI to HDMI Scaling: up to 4K 30/25/24", so if your source video is not in 4K, or not displayed full screen, or not in 60fps, this might trigger the scaling feature of the AV receiver, which can't handle more than 30fps.

Comment: @1NN I do not see how this is relevant since the online manual states in [multiple](https://manuals.marantz.com/NR1710/NA/EN/GFNFSYsavbhwwe.php) [places](https://manuals.marantz.com/NR1710/NA/EN/DRDZSYzvebvotm.php) that 4K60p 4:4:4 is explicitly supported (I deliberately enabled the "Enhanced" setting for this). I do not use any of the scaling features. I can also see in the information page in the receiver's settings that 4K60 with 4:4:4 is active when displaying a 4K60 desktop.